# CUPS - How to print the first page of a PDF to a different tray with HPPaperSource? (Using an HP LaserJet M601)

Tags: cups

I've got an HP LaserJet M601 to replace an ageing HP 4250 but I'm having problems using CUPS to print PDFs from the command line.

Basically, I can't find a way to get `AP_FIRSTPAGE_InputSlot` to work with the HP M601.

It's essential that page 1 of the PDF is printed to Tray 3 and all other pages are printed to Tray 2. This is the command for the existing HP 4250 and it works great:

`lp -d HP_LaserJet_4250 -o AP_FIRSTPAGE_InputSlot=Tray3_500 -o orientation-requested=6 file.pdf`

With the new HP M601, for some reason `InputSlot` is ignored and I've got to use `HPPaperSource` to get it to use any other input tray. Hence, the following command will print **all** of `file.pdf` to Tray 3:

`lp -d HP_M601 -o HPPaperSource=Tray3 -o orientation-requested=6 test.pdf`

This however just ends up with everything being printed to Tray 2:

`lp -d HP_M601 -o AP_FIRSTPAGE_InputSlot=Tray3 -o HPPaperSource=Tray2 -o orientation-requested=6 test.pdf`

as does this:

`lp -d HP_M601 -o AP_FIRSTPAGE_HPPaperSource=Tray3 -o HPPaperSource=Tray2 -o orientation-requested=6 test.pdf`

Here's part of the CUPS error log:

```
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Looking up \"192.168.1.146\"...
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=7, addr=0x560cb5a68af8, side_cb=0x560cb49d3830)
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Printer make and model: HP HP LaserJet 600 M603
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] PID 6962 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Switching to Poppler\'s pdftops instead of Ghostscript for old HP LaserJet (\"LaserJet <number>\", no letters before <number>) printers to work around bugs in the printer\'s PS interpreters
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Running command line for pstops: pstops 43929 josh test.pdf 1 \'AP_FIRSTPAGE_InputSlot=Tray3 finishings=3 HPPaperSource=Tray2 job-uuid=urn:uuid:eeda0d3b-d585-31c3-47ab-b9f570c69e40 job-originating-host-name=192.168.1.143 date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1594196522 time-at-processing=1594196522 document-name-supplied=test.pdf\'
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Using image rendering resolution 600 dpi
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Running command line for pdftops: pdftops -level2 -origpagesizes -nocenter -r 600 /tmp/01b335f0ca8f4 -
D [08/Jul/2020:09:22:02 +0100] [Job 43929] Started filter pdftops (PID 6966)
```

Can anyone shine any light onto what seems a poorly documented problem? TIA.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi @JakeMcAllister, no. I tried for days but nothing I tried ever worked.

Comment: In the end, I used port 9100 and injected PJL commands.

This has the benefit of printing multiple jobs A LOT faster as there's no CUPS spooling or job initialisation/completion delay. That said, it still won't print pages beyond page 1 on a different page...

Perhaps that's because these printers simply don't support it and hence CUPS can't ever do it?!

Comment: So I figured out the best thing to do was to split the PDF into multiple pages and print the first page to Tray 3 and the remaining pages to Tray 2. Does the job!